# extract cells around points within a value limit in r

Tags: r

I have 12 raster data and each has 39 layers. For each raster I need to extract locations (x and y) and their values within a fixed value at locations of other spatial data (xydf).

example:

```
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
r <- stack(r, sqrt(r), r*0.2/2)
xydf <- read.csv("xydf.csv")

> xydf
     x   y layerName      T
1   30  70   layer.1  94.00
2  -40 -60   layer.1 555.00
3  100 -40   layer.2   9.69
4  -50 -20   layer.3   9.40
5   90   0   layer.2  23.55
6  120  33   layer.2  22.29
7  -90  40   layer.3  55.50
8 -100  60   layer.3  49.70
9  -50  10   layer.1 497.00
```

For example, using layer.1 at location one (30,70) I should extract grids that have values within + or - 10 around the "T" value (94.00). I have tried the extract function but I could not figure out how to do it and to run it by group (layerName).

Any ideas, please.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by question 2. Can you explain what you want with the help of an example?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If we had a single year and month, you already know how to select the maximum:

```
Monthdf %>% filter(Monthmean == max(Monthmean))
```

Selecting a range around the max is not too hard either:

```
Monthdf %>% filter(Monthmean > 0.9*max(Monthmean),
                   Monthmean < 1.1*max(Monthmean))
```

(unless you mean something different with "adjusted cells"?)

Now the problem is to do that for every month and year combination. We can use nesting to reduce the problem to what we already solved:

```
# Put processing in a function for clarity
get_points <- function(DF){
  filter(DF,
         Monthmean > 0.9*max(Monthmean),
         Monthmean < 1.1*max(Monthmean))
}

# Nest and apply the processing
Monthdf %>%
  group_by(yr, month) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(near_max = map(data, get_points))
```

To recover the results, we thus need to remove the original data and unnest. We can even add a column to keep the `max(Monthmeans)` we used, for future reference.

```
Monthdf %>%
  group_by(yr, month) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(near_max = map(data, get_points),
         partial_max = map_dbl(data, max)) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(near_max) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I did not explain the problem well. I have updated my Q.